# UITextField display formatted as currency without decimal

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to make a `UITextField` where the input is permanently displayed in currency format even though the user is editing. It should work like:

```
$0
```

user type 1

```
$1
```

user type 2

```
$12
```

user type 0

```
$120
```

user type 0

```
$1,200
```

user type 0

```
$12,000
```

I manage to get the final formatting using `NumberFormatter` like

```
textField.text = (numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Int(textField.text!)!)))?.components(separatedBy: ".")[0]
```

But once I format the text in the textField, subsequent input will cause error like:

```
$1,000
```

user type 0

```
$1,0000 //number formatter cannot recognise this as a format of currency
```

Is there anyway I can manipulate the input to allow the user to only need to key in numbers but the value is displayed in proper currency formatting with the symbol plus commas - e.g.$1,200,000. Regardless of the amount of digit - but logically up to 10 is enough.

My current textField `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is like this:

```
    textField.text = numberFormatter.number(from: textField.text!)?.description

    if(range.length == 1){  //Backspace
        if(textField.text?.characters.count == 1){
            textField.text = "$0"
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    if(string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == ""){
        textField.text = (numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Int(textField.text!)!)))?.components(separatedBy: ".")[0]
        return false
    }
    if(string == ".") {
        textField.text = (numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Int(textField.text!)!)))?.components(separatedBy: ".")[0]
        return false
    }

    textField.text = (numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Int(textField.text!.append(string)!)!)))?.components(separatedBy: ".")[0]
    return false
```

Comment: Also would be thankful if anyone can provide tips to help me reduce the amount of parenthesis and make the code look cleaner without having to add too many lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let text: NSString = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
        let finalString = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

        // 'currency' is a String extension that doews all the number styling
        amountTextField.text = finalString.currency

        // returning 'false' so that textfield will not be updated here, instead from styling extension
        return false
    }
}

extension String {
    var currency: String {
        // removing all characters from string before formatting
        let stringWithoutSymbol = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")
        let stringWithoutComma = stringWithoutSymbol.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")

        let styler = NumberFormatter()
        styler.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        styler.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        styler.currencySymbol = "$"
        styler.numberStyle = .currency

        if let result = NumberFormatter().number(from: stringWithoutComma) {
            return styler.string(from: result)!
        }

        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: That is smart! I kept thinking of using number formatter to maintain my string, I totally missed this possibility

Comment: If we type in between of the number, the cursor shifts to the end, any solution to that?

Comment: really clean way to do it, thanks @Matt, one question, is there's a way to have a max value up to 10 digits only? (including currency sign and commas)

Comment: @Mamta did you find the solution to your query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UITextField's leftView and rightView properties as shown below: This will only take care of displaying the "$" sign at the left of the input field.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x :0,y :0,width :10,height: 10))
        label.text = "$"

        self.moneyTextField.leftViewMode = .always
        self.moneyTextField.leftView = label

    }
```

Comment: Actually, I am not having much problem with the currency symbol since number formatter will help take care of it. It is the commas "," that I have trouble with. It will break the formatting once the user types more than 4 numbers in

Answer (score 0):

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  TextfieldDemo
//
//  Created by piyush sinroja on 21/12/16.


import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtDigit: UITextField!

    var strDigit: String = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x :0,y :0,width :10,height: 10))
        label.text = "$"
        self.txtDigit.leftViewMode = .always
        self.txtDigit.leftView = label

        txtDigit.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
        txtDigit.layer.masksToBounds = true
        txtDigit.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        txtDigit.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func textField(_ textFieldToChange: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if  textFieldToChange == txtDigit{
            let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted
            let compSepByCharInSet = string.components(separatedBy: aSet)
            let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joined(separator: "")

            if numberFiltered == "" {
                let new  = txtDigit.text!
                let fsf = new.substring(to: new.index(new.endIndex, offsetBy: -1))
                let currentString = fsf
                let findStr = commaStrSet(currentString: currentString)
                txtDigit.text = findStr
                return false
            }
            else{
                let currentString = (textFieldToChange.text! as NSString)
                    .replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
                let findStr = commaStrSet(currentString: currentString)
                txtDigit.text = findStr
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    func commaStrSet(currentString: String) -> String {
        var replaceStr = currentString.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
        let length = replaceStr.characters.count
        switch length {
        case 4:
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
        case 5:
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 2))
        case 6:
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 5))
        case 7:
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 2))
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 5))
        case 8:
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 4))
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 7))
        case 9:
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 2))
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 5))
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 8))
        case 10:
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 4))
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 7))
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 10))
        case 11,12,13,14,15:
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 4))
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 7))
            replaceStr.insert(",", at: replaceStr.index(replaceStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 10))
        default:
            break
        }

        return replaceStr
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the codes and it seems the offset is wrong and I tried to correct it. Thank you for helping.

Comment: no its working fine. I have made only for you, you can use your own logic

Comment: I tried another attempt to make it work with since character symbols - need to improve that later. And I double checked, your offsets are really wrong. There are return values like "$,100", "$1,00,000" and "$,10,00,00,000"

Comment: @PiyushSinroja you don't give a chance for billionaires to format their assets properly (aka "hardcoded and magic numbers are evil")